# Check for undefined and length shorter alternatives

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am curious if there are any good and shorter alternatives in modern JS to replace this kind of checks:

```
if (someVar === undefined || someVar.length === 0) { ... }
```

The question came from the current work on some obsolete codebase projects.

**UPD**: I am interested in arrays and strings atm, but would be also nice to compare different types

Comment: If you're working with strings `if (!someVar)` would work. Although it also includes `null`

Comment: please add the expected types.

Comment: I am interested in arrays and strings atm, but would be also nice to compare different types

Comment: You can try this: !!someVar

Comment: @Satif this will not work with arrays `!![] === true`

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry, didn't see question update

Comment: You can also try `Boolean(someVar)`, but it will return false for empty string and null and true for empty array. You could write a wrapper around it though, that i. e. uses array's length if `someVar` is array

Answer (score 3):

Your current code looks fine to me, but you can also alternate with the empty array and check its length:

```
if ((someVar || []).length === 0) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You could even change `array.length === 0` into `!array.length` since `0` is falsy.

Comment: @3limin4t0r true but I personally hate when I see a NOT-ed expression that's not trivial `if (!(someVar || []).length)` it's easy to miss the `!` since it's such a small part of all operations. It's also very annoying to read even if you do see it, as you need to go back and forth to understand it - `(someVar || []).length === 0` can be easily read as a single statement left to right, since `=== 0` is at the end, everything logically follows. With a `!` in front, you have to read the entire statement, then go back to the beginning understand the whole of it.

Answer (score 0):

So im assuming somVar is an array...

Functional programming is a great way to handle these kinds of things without even having if statements, I dont know what kind of "work" you need to do on the structure but lets assume some filtering mapping and reducing it to a value.

So having a function that will handle the someVar will make sure to handle the undefined case and then it will just be an empty array will will be reduced to a 0.

```
function handleSomeVar(someVar = []) {

   return someVar && someVar
    .filter(x => x.something) //lets assume we want to be sure this is defined
    .map(x => x.something) // we just want an array of primitives number/string/etc
    .reduce((memo, somehthing) => something, 0) //making the assumption that the something is a number.
}
```

or

```
const handleSomeVar = (someVar = []) => someVar && someVar
    .filter(x => x.something)
    .map(x => x.something)
    .reduce((memo, something) => something, 0)
```

implicit return arrow functions are the hardest workers in functional programming (imo)

So then result will be a something, unless someVar is empty and then it will return 0. Reduce is a great way to handle these kinds of instances where things might exist or then might not in the case of nothing well then just return the initial value.

Functional programming in this way is meaningful, debuggable, and lots of fun!

Comment: I don't think this is in any way faster, shorter or more convenient. Remember that the check is for when `someVar` is `undefined` or empty. It could also be a string. So a null-safe array operation is exactly the opposite of what's needed here.

Comment: its a contrived example of what could be possible using functional programming. when i see anything iterable i cant wait to pull out my filter, map, reduce to work on it. Variables should def not be crossing over into it might be a string, or and array territory this is very prone to type errors... anyways @VLAZ good points never the less

Answer (score 0):

You could take `toString()` and check the value for falsyness.

```js
function check(v) {
    if (!v || !v.toString()) console.log('empty');
}

check();
check([]);
check('');
```

Comment: Edge case: `check([''])`